# How to manipulate __APOLLO_STATE__ with cypress

Tags: graphql, automated-tests, cypress, react-apollo, apollo-server

We are making a server side request which returns to the client a page with an `__APOLLO_STATE__` object under `window` containing all the graphql data used by the page.
The goal is to manipulate the window in order to mock our API.

Problem is, `__APOLLO_STATE__` is not available *[onBeforeLoad](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Arguments)* but only [*onLoad*](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Arguments)

So *onBeforeLoad*

```
  cy
  .visit(url, {
    onBeforeLoad: (contentWindow) => {
      cy.stub(contentWindow, '__APOLLO_STATE__').returns('');
    },
  })
```

means the stub won't change anything because the page has already been loaded, and

*onload*

```
  cy
  .visit(url, {
    onLoad: (contentWindow) => {
      cy.stub(contentWindow, '__APOLLO_STATE__').returns('');
    },
  })
```

will throw an error because it doesn't exist

```
Cannot stub non-existent own property APOLLO_STATE
```

Has anyone that encountered this issue any suggestions?

Comment: Your E2E tests should really not be that involved in how that page is implemented. Can you not intercept the request, at least have the test double be at the network boundary?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you set on the right track, `req.reply() `or `res.send()` do the job.
Regarding the E2E, in order to mock the API the test needs to know about the structure of the graphql objects.

Comment: Sure, and ideally E2E would actually be E2E, but if you're going to mock somewhere the transport layer is a better place than tinkering with the running code in the page. That's the boundary of the client app, so leaves you free to refactor within that as long as the response stays the same.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, long story short, I agree. The API layer is not easily accessible in the current app setup so the reason I'm fiddling with the current layer is to have a backup plan in case everything else fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you could intercept every single graphql request and decide what you want to return

```
Cypress.Commands.add('mockGQL', (query, body) => {

cy.intercept('/graphql', (req) => {
    if (req.body.includes(query)) {
      req.reply({
        body: body,
        headers: {
          'access-control-allow-origin': '*'
        }
      })
    }
  })
```